# "Allow Expo Go to modify this photo" modal window

Tags: react-native, expo

SDK Version: 44.0.0

Platform: Android

When I take a photo within my Expo project, I keep getting this modal window:

[image]

This window shows up every time I take a photo and save it in the album.

How can I get rid of it? Does this happens because I missed to specify some permissions?

Here is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "myapp",
    "slug": "myapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/adaptive.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to save photos.",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use camera."
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION",
        "true"
      ],
      "package": "com.example"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had no luck with permissions in the `app.json`, but I do think I have a workaround.

I’m guessing in your code you are using `MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync` or `MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync` and passing `false`.

If you instead pass `true` to those functions, the files are copied and not moved or modified, which I think is causing the pop-up. If you want, you can then use `expo-file-system` to delete the original file so you don’t have any duplicate data.

See my answer to a similar question with sample code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76492705/22085168

Hope this is useful!